# How to only show category description and title if there's a description available?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to only show the code below if there's a category description?

```
<h2>About <?php $cat = get_the_category(); echo $cat[0]->cat_name; ?></h2>

<?php $catID = get_the_category(); echo category_description ( $catID[0] ); ?>
```

I have these codes on my single posts in Wordpress but sometimes, I forgot to add descriptions on a new category that I added. So when a user visits the post, they will just see the word **About Category** and no description at all, making it looks like an incomplete article.

I'm not a developer and I'm also not familiar with PHP. I only added that code on the single.php to show the description. But I want it not to show when there's no description available.

Hope someone can give me the exact code to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: Check what returns `category_description ( $catID[0] )` when there isn't a description.
Most probably it's just empty so you can try:

`<?PHP
if(!empty(category_description ( $catID[0] ))){
//continue
}
?>`

If that doesn't work then try `isset()`

Comment: @AlexandruBurca Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge of PHP and Wordpress codes. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practice to assign your values into variables at the top of your script before entering into HTML whenever possible. This will help prevent you making redundant calls and to debug your code better. Once you have your assigned values, you'll want to check if the value is empty. I am assuming the code you presented will always return some kind of value for index 0.

```
<?php
    $cat        = get_the_category();
    $cat_0      = $cat[0];
    $cat_0_name = $cat_0->cat_name;
    $cat_0_desc = category_description($cat_0);
?>

<?php if(!empty($cat_0_desc)): ?>
    <h2>About <?php echo $cat_0_name; ?></h2>
    <?php echo $cat_0_desc; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I should like to point out that I am choosing to use an [alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) versus the traditional brace control. This will make your code more readable and easily debugged when mixed in with HTML.

If your code is still throwing you errors, I would suggest you check your error logs as something would be happining during the `get_the_cateory()` call or that it's not returning any values resulting in error with `$cat[0]`.

Comment: This one works but the category name is not showing after the word About.

Comment: I edited the code. Replaced the `$cat_0_name;` to `$cat[0]->cat_name;`

Comment: @Katriona yeah, that's on me. When assigned the `$cat_0_name` variable I was setting it to equal `$cat->cat_name` instead of `$cat_0->cat_name`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($cat = get_the_category() && count($cat)>0) { ?>
    <!-- <?php echo print_r($cat,1); ?> -->
   <h2>About <?php echo $cat[0]->cat_name;?></h2>
   <?php echo category_description ($cat[0]->cat_id); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to use your code but it's not working on my end. It just broke the site.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo -`if` not `id` -- i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. But still, it's not working. When I add the code, the category name and description are not showing even if the category has descriptions. Also, the "About" word is showing too...

Comment: yikes. I had another typo, sorry moving too fast. that is fixed in the code above. However, I don' t know what your $cat looks like. Is it an array or a single object?

Comment: I added a debug in the answer. Can you try it and look at the html it generates and paste in what shows up in the `<!--` comment?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your code but it still didn't work. The code that was shared by Daerik was working when I used the code that you gave. Thanks again.